# Copy from one word document to another word document

Tags: c#, openxml

I am trying to copy data from one word file to another by specific parts of the word. For example I want to copy only the header or the footer of word document 1 to word document 2 or I want to copy table 1 from word document 1 to table 1 in word document 2.

```
using (WordprocessingDocument firstDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(textBox2.Text, false))
using (WordprocessingDocument secondDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Create(textBox3.Text, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
{
    foreach (var part in firstDocument.Parts)
    {
        secondDocument.AddPart(part.OpenXmlPart, part.RelationshipId);                   
    }
```

How can I change this code to copy specific parts of firstDocument to secondDocument (Example : Table 1 ).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use [LINQ where](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.8) to select only needed parts

```
using System.Linq;
...
foreach (var part in firstDocument.Parts.Where(/* insert here your condition*/))
...
```